# What is the LibGit2Sharp equivalent of 'git pull'?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'm trying to merge changes from the remote branch into the local repository, however I've been unable to get this to work properly -- likely misunderstanding of the implementation. Fetching seems to work fine, as I can see the updates on the server, but I think I'm breaking something when *attempting* to pull.

I've tried:

```
repo.Checkout( branch.TrackedBranch, CheckoutOptions.None, OnCheckoutProgress );
```

This seems to do what you would expect from a Clone call. I can also not find a method to merge. As I've read, `git pull` is just like calling a fetch, then a merge.

I've looked at some of the tests in the repo, such as the MergeFixture, but it didn't seem to be what I was hoping it would be.

Comment: This would be much better asked on http://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp - it's a very active community.  But to answer your question, merge is in progress.  I'd be happy to discuss more on github...

Comment: I know it's active there, but I asked a question in the issue tracker, and was directed to ask here, so I have been :)

Comment: @EdwardThomson: Well, according to the **[README](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/README.md)**: *"Usage or programming related question? Post it on StackOverflow using the tag libgit2sharp"* ;-)

Comment: @nulltoken Thanks for the backup :-) Any idea how long we're talking about for merge implementation? I was using your GitSharp first, and it seems a bit more complete than LibGit2Sharp (I'm pretty sure merge was implemented).

Comment: *"Any idea how long we're talking about for merge implementation?"* -> Nope. I'll update the answer when it's ready.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Pull` is indeed the combination of `Fetch` and `Merge`.

- `Fetch` is ready
- `Merge` is in progress (as stated by @EdwardThomson)

> I've looked at some of the tests in the repo, such as the MergeFixture, but it didn't seem to be what I was hoping it would be.

As the *complete* merge process isn't available yet, there aren't many tests yet. However, `MergeFixture.cs` includes *some* aspects of the merge

- Detection of conflicts/unmerged entries
- Retrieval of the branch(es) being merged

There are other related bits in the `CommitFixture.cs` as well

- Cleanup of potential merge metadata on Commit
- Automatic inclusion of parents when issue a merge Commit

Libgit2 also includes some **[lower level bits](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/include/git2/index.h#L480-564)** to deal with conflicts that have been resolved by the user.

### Update

**Merge** feature is now available in LibGit2Sharp (see **[pull request #608](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/608)**)

Answer (score 12):

**Update as of April 2014**

A convenience method of `Pull` has been added to LibGit2Sharp.

```
repo.Network.Pull(signature, pullOptions);
```

You can find more basic usages in the [test fixtures](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/NetworkFixture.cs#L136).

Comment: Network no longer has a Pull operation as of version 0.25.0 ... there is a new static Commands object with a Pull function however.

Comment: See my answer here for 2022/23 versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062476/libgit2sharp-replace-the-git-pull-command/75294195#75294195